# Should there be a penalty for mistagging your question?

Tags: discussion

I've recently been trying to stem the tide of questions about how to develop using Cocoa or iOS issues that are tagged [Xcode] when they're really not Xcode questions. It feels like trying to hold back the evil of parsing HTML with RegEx.

Should there be a penalty to people who post questions with bad tags? I guess that would mean the privilege of retagging might need a higher prerequisite reputation.

Comment: How about a comment in addition to the downvote?

Comment: Here is my comment. I [disagree](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) with this. Why should there be a penalty? What kind of penalty? Do you think people are mis-tagging on purpose to be evil? (Shouldn't this be tagged "feature request"? arrrgh -1)

Comment: Votes should be based on the content, not the user. If you edit the tags, there's no reason to downvote, since the error has been fixed.

Comment: Yeah, I don't downvote stuff when I fix tags. And I don't think people mistag on purpose, but they don't seem to think about it. Even users with fairly high rep misuse the Xcode tag. I thought penalties were for things that degraded the quality of the site. Tag-relevance seems important. But I can understand the point of view that such a penalty would cause more problems than it would solve.

Comment: Almo, if people are mis-tagging then do you suppose they are mis-searching as well and have the wrong "favorited" tags? Just educate the user, there's no need to penalize for something like this, being clueless is already enough penalty.

Comment: Nevermind. I took `How about a comment in addition to the downvote?` as a question if you should downvote questions with bad tags.

Comment: Ah, hehe. I had just gotten two downvotes and no comments. I know that's how meta works, but I was genuinely curious about what other people thought beyond "disagree". I'm a game designer, and find these issues very interesting.

Comment: There should be a penalty for stacking your (not you specifically, but a user in general) question title with tags!

Comment: +1, this is really annoying! All n00bs and a lot of more experienced iOS developers are consitently tagging their questions Xcode - man who read this, also read the tag wiki of Xcode on SO - you'll find out why this is a serious problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Should there be a penalty to people who post questions with bad tags?

No, there shouldn't. Many of the mistagged questions are from new users and penalizing them for this would simply discourage them from asking.

It is easy enough to edit the tags (or suggest tag edits).